# In a Redis cluster how do I determine the peak memory usage of all nodes using Spring Data Redis Reactive API?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-data-redis-reactive

I wanted to build an L2 Hibernate Cache using a Redis cluster in Spring Boot (I've done that part already) but I want it to stop using Redis when a certain threshold is reached.

So I was thinking of either remaining memory bytes or remaining memory percentage be a parameter I pass into the cache system.  That's relatively easy enough.

The question I have is how to actually determine the value so I can compare it across all the nodes of the cluster so if any of the nodes are almost full it will stop.

I am thinking it is around the use of the [`MEMORY STATS` API](https://redis.io/commands/memory-stats/) and somehow get a list of all the nodes in the cluster and then do a max.

Just need to find out the actual numbers to use.  There is `total.allocated` so I guess that's the upper limit.  Looking specifically using the Reactive API as well.